# Fetch 2 URLRequests at the same time on one tableView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift, in the last 72 hours I searched everywhere to find an answer for my problem but with no luck.
I created my first app using Xcode 10, Swift 4.2 My app successfully fetches news data from newsapi.org but I need to fetch data from 2 different sources on the same tableView at the same time. Please take a look at my code: Your help is extremely appreciated!

```
func fetchArticles(){ 
    if let articlesFromJson = jsodTemp!["articles"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
                    for articleFromJson in articlesFromJson {
                        let article = Article()
                        if let title = articleFromJson["title"] as? String, let author = articleFromJson["author"] as? String, let desc = articleFromJson["description"] as? String, let url = articleFromJson["url"] as? String, let urlToImage = articleFromJson["urlToImage"] as? String, let pubDate = articleFromJson["publishedAt"] as? String {

                            article.author = author
                            article.desc = desc
                            article.headline = title
                            article.url = url
                            article.imageUrl = urlToImage
                            article.pubDate = pubDate

                        }
                        self.articles?.append(article)
}
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        print("Call API")

        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=396c2db56f7541cd93fb8b5cec9f447b")!)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error as Any)
                return
            }

            self.articles = [Article]()
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]
                // Save data for offline mode
                UserDefaults.standard.set(json, forKey: "offlineUse");
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

                if let articlesFromJson = json["articles"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
                    for articleFromJson in articlesFromJson {
                        let article = Article()
                        if let title = articleFromJson["title"] as? String, let author = articleFromJson["author"] as? String, let desc = articleFromJson["description"] as? String, let url = articleFromJson["url"] as? String, let urlToImage = articleFromJson["urlToImage"] as? String, let pubDate = articleFromJson["publishedAt"] as? String {

                            article.author = author
                            article.desc = desc
                            article.headline = title
                            article.url = url
                            article.imageUrl = urlToImage
                            article.pubDate = pubDate

                        }
                        self.articles?.append(article)
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }

            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "articleCell", for: indexPath) as! ArticleCell

        cell.title.text = self.articles?[indexPath.item].headline
        cell.desc.text = self.articles?[indexPath.item].desc
        cell.author.text = self.articles?[indexPath.item].author
        cell.pubDate.text = self.articles?[indexPath.item].pubDate
        cell.imgView.downloadImage(from: ((self.articles?[indexPath.item].imageUrl)!)!)
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a temp Variable called ready. Add one if it has successfully loaded one data source. If it's two then reload tableView.

```
 var ready : Int = 0{
    didSet{
        if ready == 2 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }
    }
}

func fetchArticles(){
    ready = 0;
    self.articles = [Article]()

    if let articlesFromJson = jsodTemp!["articles"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
        for articleFromJson in articlesFromJson {
            let article = Article()
            if let title = articleFromJson["title"] as? String, let author = articleFromJson["author"] as? String, let desc = articleFromJson["description"] as? String, let url = articleFromJson["url"] as? String, let urlToImage = articleFromJson["urlToImage"] as? String, let pubDate = articleFromJson["publishedAt"] as? String {

                article.author = author
                article.desc = desc
                article.headline = title
                article.url = url
                article.imageUrl = urlToImage
                article.pubDate = pubDate

            }
            self.articles?.append(article)
        }
        ready += 1;
    }




let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=396c2db56f7541cd93fb8b5cec9f447b")!)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error)   in

if error != nil {
    print(error as Any)
    return
}


do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]
    // Save data for offline mode
    UserDefaults.standard.set(json, forKey: "offlineUse");
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    if let articlesFromJson = json["articles"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
        for articleFromJson in articlesFromJson {
            let article = Article()
            if let title = articleFromJson["title"] as? String, let author = articleFromJson["author"] as? String, let desc = articleFromJson["description"] as? String, let url = articleFromJson["url"] as? String, let urlToImage = articleFromJson["urlToImage"] as? String, let pubDate = articleFromJson["publishedAt"] as? String {

                article.author = author
                article.desc = desc
                article.headline = title
                article.url = url
                article.imageUrl = urlToImage
                article.pubDate = pubDate

            }
            self.articles?.append(article)
        }
    }
   self.ready += 1

} catch let error {
    print(error)
}

}
task.resume()
}
```

As suggested, you may use DispatchGroup() if you have multiple asynchronous data loading.

```
 func fetchArticles (){
      ready = 0;
self.articles = [Article]()


       let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup() 
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        if let articlesFromJson = jsodTemp!["articles"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
    for articleFromJson in articlesFromJson {
        let article = Article()
        if let title = articleFromJson["title"] as? String, let author = articleFromJson["author"] as? String, let desc = articleFromJson["description"] as? String, let url = articleFromJson["url"] as? String, let urlToImage = articleFromJson["urlToImage"] as? String, let pubDate = articleFromJson["publishedAt"] as? String {

            article.author = author
            article.desc = desc
            article.headline = title
            article.url = url
            article.imageUrl = urlToImage
            article.pubDate = pubDate

        }
        self.articles?.append(article)
    }

}



        dispatchGroup.leave()  //  self.ready += 1 

        dispatchGroup.enter()


 let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=396c2db56f7541cd93fb8b5cec9f447b")!)

 let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error)   in

if error != nil {
print(error as Any)
return
}


 do {
   let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]
// Save data for offline mode
UserDefaults.standard.set(json, forKey: "offlineUse");
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

if let articlesFromJson = json["articles"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
    for articleFromJson in articlesFromJson {
        let article = Article()
        if let title = articleFromJson["title"] as? String, let author = articleFromJson["author"] as? String, let desc = articleFromJson["description"] as? String, let url = articleFromJson["url"] as? String, let urlToImage = articleFromJson["urlToImage"] as? String, let pubDate = articleFromJson["publishedAt"] as? String {

            article.author = author
            article.desc = desc
            article.headline = title
            article.url = url
            article.imageUrl = urlToImage
            article.pubDate = pubDate

        }
        self.articles?.append(article)
    }
}
dispatchGroup.leave() //  self.ready += 1 

} catch let error {
print(error)
 }

 }
task.resume()



 _ = dispatchGroup.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

 }
```

Comment: The use of `DispatchGroup` is a more typical solution.

Comment: Yes.  I think his case is  not too complicated.